How do I clean up this mesh after importing from 3dsmax?
I am very new to Blender. Just installed it last night!
Trying to import all my models from 3dsMax to Blender. I want to smooth out an area. It looks fine in 3ds max but not in Blender. See image. There are lots of triangles around the head of the snake. I tried converting them to quads and using the smooth option but no success.
Thanks for your help.
Link to blender scene file

Edit...
Going into Object mode and right-clicking then choosing shade smooth and un-checking "Keep Sharp Edges" and then going to sculpting to smooth things out.
Is there a better way?
Edit #2
The wings are not attached and when I move them they snap back. I would like to keep the animation of my 3dsmax files if I can,
Thanks.

Please include your image directly in your question rather than just a link to it! See How to upload an image to a post.

fixed, sorry about that

Try to go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data, also maybe select all in Edit mode and M > Merge by Distance? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

I sorta got it working. But maybe someone has tips to make it better. Thanks,

